# What field can you use to track queue origin? (i.e. what went to X queue in the last 30 days)

Tags: reporting, queue

Currently our company is using "Ticket Owner" field to assign a ticket to a queue.

Issue: unable to track historically how many tickets went into that queue

Example:
Queue: Escalations

Ticket Owner: Escalations

Per process, the ticket owner changes to the User working on the ticket. So unless you know the person who worked on that queue, no way to know the initial queue it went to.

Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can write a trigger whenever the owner changes from queue id to a user id. And in this trigger store the initial queue name in a text field, which can be used for reporting.